# Infopath Cannot publish: InfoPath either cannot connect to the data source or the service has timed out

Tags: infopath

I updated the Infopath Form and when I try to publish it, its taking to almost 1 hour only to get this error message:

InfoPath either cannot connect to the data source or the service has timed out.